# MySql select 1 week & 1 Month advance date from Current date

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

i want to get the list of date which is going to expire in a week or a month...
MySQL, and field is TIMESTAMP.

i tried below queries...

> SELECT CERT_ID, date(CERTVALIDITY) 
>       FROM mst_CERT WHERE date(CERTVALIDITY) > now() - interval 1 week ORDER BY CERTVALIDITY;

This returns all the dates from current date

> SELECT date(CERTVALIDITY) from mst_CERT where curdate() =
>   DATE(DATE_SUB(CERTVALIDITY, INTERVAL 1 week));

returns nothing...

> SELECT date(DATE_SUB(CERTVALIDITY, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) from mst_CERT;

returns nothing...

```
| CT00078      | 2020-02-28  |
| CT00098      | 2020-02-29  |
| CT00011      | 2020-03-31  |
| CT00012      | 2020-03-31  |
| CT00013      | 2020-03-31  |
| CT00014      | 2020-03-31  |
| CT00075      | 2020-03-31  |
| CT00055      | 2020-03-31  |
| CT00056      | 2021-03-31  |
```

Comment: what columns do you have in your table?

Comment: i have , cert_id, cert_name, cert_type, CERTVALIDITY, active columns in my table... CERTVALIDITY is timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will show CERT_ID's outside of a 7 day period.

```
SELECT      CERT_ID, date(CERTVALIDITY) 
FROM        mst_CERT 
WHERE       date(CERTVALIDITY) > (NOW() + INTERVAL 7 day) 
ORDER BY    date(CERTVALIDITY);
```

This will show you valid CERT_ID's within a 7 day period.

```
SELECT      CERT_ID, date(CERTVALIDITY) 
FROM        mst_CERT 
WHERE       date(CERTVALIDITY) BETWEEN NOW() AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 7 day) 
ORDER BY    date(CERTVALIDITY);
```

Comment: i tried this... but still returning all the dates from current dates... not just 7 days....
+-------------------------------+
| date(CERTVALIDITY) |
+-------------------------------+
| 2020-02-27                    |
| 2020-02-28                    |
| 2020-02-29                    |
| 2020-03-01                    |
| 2020-03-03                    |
| 2020-03-31                    |
| 2020-03-31                    |
| 2020-03-31                    |

Comment: I've updated my answer to show any rows between now and 7 days from now. This would show you your valid cert IDs within 7 days. Simply change the days for a different time period.

Comment: Thanks the updated query is worked well for me... why the > is not work but between command works fine...

Answer (score 1):

Your first query is almost right. You made a mistake of subtracting interval of 1 week but you actually had to add interval.

```
SELECT CERT_ID, DATE(CERTVALIDITY) 
FROM ms_CERT 
WHERE DATE(CERTVALIDITY) < NOW() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND DATE(CERTVALIDITY) > NOW()
ORDER BY CERTVALIDITY;
```

Above Query will return following result

```
| CT00078      | 2020-02-28  |
| CT00098      | 2020-02-29  |
```

Comment: The above query returns 1 week from today and also returns old dates too... from lastyear too

Comment: @uday , you can add AND DATE(CERTVALIDITY) > NOW() on where condition as i have edited to my solution.